# JavaScript: How do I keep a radio button checked after form submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http, radio-button

With (Vanilla) JavaScript, how do I maintain the 'checked' value of a radio button after a user submits a form?

I have two tables, one for Local Storage, the other using a Database. If the user wants to switch between these tables they simply check the radio box.

When the user updates the form using the Database table, the page reloads and Local Storage becomes 'checked', even if the Database table is still displayed.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfVbI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this that if the form submits a form, it reloads the page with #local or #community in the URL (depending on which radio box was chosen).

Then add something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("#community") > -1) { // check if URL contains #community in it
       document.getElementById("myCustomCheckBox").checked; // set your checkbox checked
    }
});
</script>
```

You can also avoid reloading the page and using AJAX to make the same happen without reloading, but the above solution is what I can think of if for some reason the reload is necessary.